# How do I set a background image in Actionscript?

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript, background, actionscript-2

I have looked around for about two hours now and I can't seem to find the command to convert this little piece of code to change the ball colour to a bitmap:

```
on(release){
myColor = new Color(_root.ball_mc);
myColor.setRGB(0xFF0000);
}
```

Comment: Is the bitmap already in the swf or do you need to load an external file?

Comment: @jhocking: the bitmap can be either.... which ever is easiest...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your ball is a vector circle, what you can do is use it as the mask on a bitmap object:

http://www.republicofcode.com/tutorials/flash/as3masking/

Comment: Yeah that kind of thing.... back the background of the ball my image... but then i need to make a custom shape with the background of the image

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. If you set the ball as the mask of the bitmap object, then you'll get a circle filled with the bitmap image. Is that not what you're after?

Comment: i need to do it dynamically and be able to change the background image from one to another

Answer (score 0):

if it is a circle you're drawing, you can use beginBitmapFill

[here](http://mmedia.glos.ac.uk/mu210/T13/T13_40_AS3.html) is an example

Comment: Thats cool but i just realised i will actually need to pull an image from the same directory :-( and put it in to a custom shape i am still yet to do

Comment: lee, are you a native english-speaker? I don't want to criticize you too harshly if this is a language barrier.